# How to get 1 slicer to change 2 datasets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get one slicer to filter 2 pivot tables from 2 different data sets. For example i have 1 pivot for Table1 and one for Table2 nd i need the one slicer to change both

I have tried adding both to a data model but am unable to create a relationship due to duplicates (these are unavoidable and cannot be removed).

Is there any other way?

Comment: Something like this link?  [Connect Slicers to Multiple Excel Pivot Tables](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/connect-slicers-to-multiple-excel-pivot-tables/)

Comment: Similar however that link is for pivots linked to one dataset, my problem is linking them to multiple datasets

Comment: So create a third, 'bridge' table which comprises a unique list of your slicer values, then create relationships between this new table and your two current tables.

Comment: Thanks Jos, the issue with this is not being able to add calculated fields to the pivot table like you can with non-data model pivots. My pivots are 50% calculated fields